# BeanCreationException with Hibernate mapping (using Spring and Maven)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I am trying to correctly establish the relationships between the different entities.

Watching at the code I think everything is ok and coherent (I have verified that the properties have the same name as established in the Hibernate mapping configuration file), but, well, it does not compile. So it is evident it is not OK. The error shown is the following:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating
bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.
PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in class path
resource [spring.cfg.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
resource [spring.cfg.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested
exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate
default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
```

The pom.xml file is the following

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.igalia.mswl</groupId>
<artifactId>snippr</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>snippr Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<!-- =================================================================== -->
<!-- Default values for properties.These default values are expected to
    be valid for most profiles.Specific profiles can overwrite values when necessary. -->
<properties>
    <!-- Data source properties -->
    <dataSource.user>test</dataSource.user>
    <dataSource.password>test</dataSource.password>
    <dataSource.jndiName>jdbc/testdb</dataSource.jndiName>
    <testDataSource.user>${dataSource.user}</testDataSource.user>
    <testDataSource.password>${dataSource.password}</testDataSource.password>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <spring-security.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
</properties>

<!-- =================================================================== -->
<!-- Profiles. * The build is always executed by selecting at least two
    non-exclusive profiles. By default, such profiles are "dev" and "postgresql"
    (meaning "use PostgreSQL assuming a development environment"). * General
    profiles. There are two general (database-independent) profiles: "dev" and
    "prod". The former is used for development (including testing) and the latter
    is used for production (including testing). As shown below, two dataSources
    (databases schemas) are used in both profiles: one for running (dataSource)
    and another one for the Maven test fase (testDataSource). Note the Maven
    test fase is executed both with development and production profiles. * Database-specific
    profiles. There is a profile for each supported database. * Specific profiles
    can be defined to better adapt to a particular environment by overwriting/adding
    properties and/or including other chunks of valid XML. * Usage: + mvn <<goal>>
    => Execute <<goal>> with default profiles. + mvn -Pdev,<<database>> <<goal>
    => Execute <<goal>> with "dev" and <<database>> profiles. + mvn -Pprod,<<database>>
    <<goal>> => Execute <<goal>> with "prod" and <<database>> profiles. + Note
    that when using -P option all desired profiles must be specified (e.g. "-Pprod"
    with the intention to select "prod" and the default database profile is not
    correct; "-Pprod,<<database>>" must be used instead). * Examples: + mvn <<goal>>
    + mvn -Ppostgresql,prod <<goal>> + mvn -Ppostgresql,dev <<goal>> -->

<profiles>
    <!-- Development profile -->
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <!-- SnippR environment properties -->
            <snippr.mode>dev</snippr.mode>
            <!-- Hibernate properties -->
            <hibernate.show_sql>true</hibernate.show_sql>
            <hibernate.format_sql>true</hibernate.format_sql>
            <hibernate.use_sql_comments>true</hibernate.use_sql_comments>
            <hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>update</hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <!-- MySQL profile -->
    <profile>
        <id>mysql</id>
        <properties>
            <!-- JDBC driver properties -->
            <jdbcDriver.groupId>mysql</jdbcDriver.groupId>
            <jdbcDriver.artifactId>mysql-connector-java</jdbcDriver.artifactId>
            <jdbcDriver.version>5.0.5</jdbcDriver.version>
            <jdbcDriver.className>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</jdbcDriver.className>
            <!-- Data source properties -->
            <dataSource.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb</dataSource.url>
            <!-- Hibernate properties -->
            <hibernate.dialect>org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</hibernate.dialect>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <!-- PostgreSQL profile -->
    <profile>
        <id>postgresql</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <!-- JDBC driver properties -->
            <jdbcDriver.groupId>postgresql</jdbcDriver.groupId>
            <jdbcDriver.artifactId>postgresql</jdbcDriver.artifactId>
            <jdbcDriver.version>8.3-603.jdbc4</jdbcDriver.version>
            <jdbcDriver.className>org.postgresql.Driver</jdbcDriver.className>
            <!-- Data source properties -->
            <dataSource.url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/testdb</dataSource.url>
            <!-- Hibernate properties -->
            <hibernate.dialect>org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</hibernate.dialect>
            <!-- <databasetable.prefix>public.</databasetable.prefix> -->
        </properties>
    </profile>

</profiles>

<!-- =================================================================== -->
<!-- Repository management -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>zkoss</id>
        <url>http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<!-- =================================================================== -->
<!-- Dependency management -->
<dependencies>

    <!-- JUnit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ZK -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
        <artifactId>zk</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
        <artifactId>zul</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
        <artifactId>zkplus</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
        <artifactId>zkspring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
        <artifactId>zkspring-security</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JDBC driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${jdbcDriver.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${jdbcDriver.artifactId}</artifactId>
        <version>${jdbcDriver.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>snippr</finalName>

    <!-- =============================================================== -->
    <!-- Filtering -->
    <resources>

        <!-- Apply filtering to files matching the following expressions in src/main/resources. -->
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>*spring.cfg.xml</include>
                <include>*hibernate.cfg.xml</include>
                <include>jetty-env.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>

        <!-- Continue considering resources the files in src/main/resources, but
            without applying filtering. -->
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <testResources>
        <!-- Apply filtering to files matching the following expressions in src/test/resources. -->
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>*spring.cfg-test.xml</include>
                <include>*hibernate.cfg-test.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </testResource>

        <!-- Continue considering resources the files in src/test/resources, but
            without applying filtering. -->
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>

    <!-- Maven plugin -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.18</version>
            <configuration>
                <jettyEnvXml>target/classes/jetty-env.xml</jettyEnvXml>
                <reload>manual</reload>
                <stopPort>9966</stopPort>
                <stopKey>stop</stopKey>

                <!-- Log to the console. -->
                <requestLog implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.NCSARequestLog">
                    <append>true</append>
                </requestLog>
            </configuration>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>${jdbcDriver.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>${jdbcDriver.artifactId}</artifactId>
                    <version>${jdbcDriver.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>
</project>
```

And the Snippr.hbm.xml is the following one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="org.snippr.business.entities" default-access="field">

<!-- User -->
<class name="User" table="users">
    <id name="id" access="property">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="firstName" column="first_name" />
    <property name="lastName" column="last_name" />
    <property name="username" column="user_name" unique="true" />
    <property name="password" column="password" />
    <property name="email" column="email" />
    <property name="enabled" column="enabled" />
    <property name="accountNonExpired" column="account_non_expired" />
    <property name="credentialsNonExpired" column="credentials_non_expired" />
    <property name="accountNonLocked" column="account_non_locked" />

    <set name="roles" table="users_roles" lazy="false">
        <key column="user_id" />
        <many-to-many column="role_id" entity-name="org.snippr.business.entities.Role" />
    </set>
    <set name="snippets" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" >
        <key column="user_id" />
        <one-to-many class="org.snippr.business.entities.Snippet" />
    </set>
    <set name="labels" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" >
        <key column="user_id" />
        <one-to-many class="org.snippr.business.entities.Label" />
    </set>
    <set name="comments" inverse="true"  cascade="all-delete-orphan" >
        <key column="user_id" />
        <one-to-many class="org.snippr.business.entities.Comment" />
    </set>
</class>

<!-- Role -->
<class name="Role" table="roles">
    <id name="id" access="property">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="roleName" column="role_name" />
</class>

<!-- Snippet -->
<class name="Snippet" table="snippet">
    <id name="id" access="property">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="title" unique="true" />
    <property name="description" />
    <set name="snippetCodes" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
        <key column="snippet_id" />
        <one-to-many class="org.snippr.business.entities.SnippetCode" />
    </set>
    <many-to-one name="user" class="org.snippr.business.entities.User"
        column="user_id" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="label" class="org.snippr.business.entities.Label"
        column="label_id" not-null="true" />
</class>

<!-- SnippetCode -->
<class name="SnippetCode" table="snippet_code">
    <id name="id" access="property">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="code" unique="false" type="text" />
    <many-to-one name="snippet" class="org.snippr.business.entities.Snippet"
        column="snippet_id" not-null="true" />
</class>

<!-- Label -->
<class name="Label" table="label">
    <id name="id" access="property">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="name" unique="false" />

    <many-to-one name="user" class="org.snippr.business.entities.User"
        column="user_id" not-null="true" />
    <set name="snippets" inverse="true" cascade="save-update">
        <key column="label_id" />
        <one-to-many class="org.snippr.business.entities.Snippet" />
    </set>
</class>

<!-- Comment -->
<class name="Comment" table="comment">
    <id name="id" access="property">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="text" column="text"/>
    <property name="email" column="email"/>
    <property name="url" column="url"/>

    <many-to-one name="user" class="org.snippr.business.entities.User"
        column="user_id" not-null="true" />
</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

The .jar files downloaded by Maven are the following

- antlr-2.7.6.jar aopalliance-1.0.jar aspectjrt-1.6.8.jar
- aspectjtools-1.5.4.jar aspectjweaver-1.6.8.jar bsh-2.0b4.jar
- commons-collections-3.1.jar commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec-1.1.1.jar
- hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
- hibernate-core-3.6.5.Final.jar hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
- javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar jta-1.1.jar log4j-1.2.16.jar
- postgresql-8.3-603.jdbc4.jar slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
- spring-aop-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- spring-context-support-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
- spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar spring-expression-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
- spring-jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- spring-security-acl-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- spring-security-config-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- spring-security-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- spring-security-taglibs-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- zcommon-5.0.11.jar zcommons-el-1.1.0.jar zk-5.0.11.jar
- zkplus-5.0.11.jar zkspring-core-3.0.jar zkspring-security-3.0.jar
- zul-5.0.11.jar zweb-5.0.11.jar

Any Java expert is capable of seeing what happens here or give any clues? As I said, I have verified the name properties and I don't see any typo error.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error occurs when you don't have javassist.jar in your classpath. As I see you declared it. Ensure that you have all getters and setters for your class properties.

Answer (score 0):

Oh shit! I am feeling really stupid. I was convinced I had verified all the instance's properties.

The bug is caused because of an error in one of the classes called "Comment". I have read the latest error in the stacktrace, but if I keep on reading the stacktrace I can find the following:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: field [user] not found on org.snippr.business.entities.Comment
at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getField(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:182)
at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getField(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:189)
at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getField(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:174)
at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getGetter(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:197)
at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getGetter(Property.java:304)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertyGetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:297)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:155)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:77)
```

There's not property 'user' in the class Comment. There's an inconsistency between the mapping and the class Comment. **The mapping refers to property user, but Comment had property Set users**. The class is incorrect (I have made the relationship 1-N in the wrong sense).